# Какие подходы построения приложения существуют в Android?

Tags: java, android

Я знаю два подхода:

1. Использовать Activity для каждого окна. Первый случай хорош простотой, но есть проблемы с производительностью и захламлённостью `AndroidManifest.xml`.
2. Использовать фрагменты и одну хост Activity. Такой способ хорош производительностью и чистотой в `AndroidManifest.xml`, но трудно реализовать его, так как надо писать много кода и проверок.

Если бы была какая-нибудь библиотека, которая бы отвечала за все моменты по созданию фрагментов, извлечению их из стеков, действия по нажатии back и т.д., то думаю данный подход был бы лучше.

Какие ещё существуют подходы в построении Android приложений?

Comment: Я думаю, вы не совсем правильно трактуете термин "архитектура". Архитектура приложения не зависит от того фрагменты вы используете или активити.

Comment: Здесь нет волшебного заклинания, зависимость от UX решений, где-то так лучше, где-то так, по опыту переделывается быстро, для меня с активити перенести во фрагмент проще, а для хорошего менеджмента стека, пишу утилитарный класс, там все довольно просто, гугл сам рекомендует так делать

Comment: Простые ответы на сложные вопросы, как правило, неправильные.

Comment: "грязнотой в manifest" - это как? Интересно узнать подробности :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/terrakok/Cicerone - одна из библиотек для навигации в андроид, там есть стандартный менеджер для фрагментов, можно свой написать для чего угодно.

некоторые разработчики отказываются от фрагментов и пишут экраны на вьюхах. вот популярные библиотеки:

https://github.com/Zhuinden/simple-stack

https://github.com/square/flow

https://github.com/bluelinelabs/Conductor

В целом проще всего писать на активити. Если нужна сложная навигация и переиспользуемые модули, то гугл рекомендует использовать фрагменты. Но у них сложный жизненный цикл и не совсем удачное API, поэтому многие вместо фрагментов наследуются от лэйаутов и пишут логику отображения там. Но у вьюх нет логики навигации, которая есть у фрагментов, для этого и используются либы типа флоу и симплбэкстэк. Либо бэкстэк и роутер пишется самостоятельно. Вот у этого парня https://hackernoon.com/@Zhuinden есть куча статей о том как не использовать фрагменты, аргументы против фрагментов и за вьюхи, советую ознакомиться, чтобы лучше понимать проблему.

И вот в довесок набор примеров от профи: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture